# FullCalendar: modal for displaying events is triggered multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, fullcalendar

I have been struggling with an issue that I wasn't expecting.
I have a FullCalendar2 instance on my site and all event actions (insert/update/show) are handled through a Bootstrap modal box. Oddly, the "shown" and "hidden" events of the modal box appear to be "remembering" all previous "select" clicks on the calendar.

Here's my code:

```
 select: function(start, end) {
    console.log('select start');
    $('#mymodal').modal({
       show  : true
    }).on('loaded.bs.modal', function(e) {
        console.log('loaded');
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    }).on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        console.log('shown ' + start.format('DD.MM.YYYY'));
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
        console.log('hidden ' + start.format('DD.MM.YYYY'));
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    });
    console.log('select end');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
},
```

[Link to working JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pdqK/3/) - *to see the error, check the console output* after clicking on different empty days (click at least on two different days).

As you can see, the console logs all clicks done on the calendar. I don't know why. Tried to clear the selection, clear the modal box (without destroying it, as it would render it unusable).

Any idea on how to prevent the "shown" and "hidden" methods of the modal box to be called multiple times?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: have you figured out a way as of yet ?